# Linking formview to a gridview

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to link the selected row in gridview and display it in the form view but each time when I choose the item in gridview, it selects a specific row in the gridview and displays it.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.Grades1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Code" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="921px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GradeName" HeaderText="GradeName" SortExpression="GradeName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GradeGroupName" HeaderText="GradeGroupName" SortExpression="GradeGroupName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GradeCons" HeaderText="GradeCons" SortExpression="GradeCons" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GradeNameCons" HeaderText="GradeNameCons" SortExpression="GradeNameCons" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Dev201601ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Grades.Grade AS Code, Grades.GradeName, GradeGroups.GradeGroupName, Grades.GradeCons, Grades.GradeNameCons FROM Grades LEFT OUTER JOIN GradeGroups ON GradeGroups.GradeGroup = Grades.GradeGroup ORDER BY Code"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <br />
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Grade" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Width="926px">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                Grade:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Grade") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeName:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeName") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeGroupName:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeGroupNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeGroupName") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeStepAmount:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeStepAmountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeStepAmount") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeOrder:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeOrderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeOrder") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeCons:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeConsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeCons") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeNameCons:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeNameConsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeNameCons") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeFromDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeFromDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeFromDate") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeToDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeToDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeToDate") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                Grade:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Grade") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeName:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeName") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeGroupName:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeGroupNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeGroupName") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeStepAmount:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeStepAmountTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeStepAmount") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeOrder:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeOrderTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeOrder") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeCons:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeConsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeCons") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeNameCons:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeNameConsTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeNameCons") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeFromDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeFromDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeFromDate") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeToDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="GradeToDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeToDate") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                Grade:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Grade") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeName:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeName") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeGroupName:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeGroupNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeGroupName") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeStepAmount:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeStepAmountLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeStepAmount") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeOrder:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeOrderLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeOrder") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeCons:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeConsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeCons") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeNameCons:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeNameConsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeNameCons") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeFromDate:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeFromDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeFromDate") %>' />
                <br />
                GradeToDate:
                <asp:Label ID="GradeToDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GradeToDate") %>' />
                <br />

                <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />

            </ItemTemplate>
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        </asp:FormView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Dev201601ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Grades.Grade, Grades.GradeName, GradeGroups.GradeGroupName, Grades.GradeStepAmount, Grades.GradeOrder, Grades.GradeCons, Grades.GradeNameCons, Grades.GradeFromDate, Grades.GradeToDate FROM Grades LEFT OUTER JOIN GradeGroups ON GradeGroups.GradeGroup = Grades.GradeGroup" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Grades WHERE (Grade = @Grade)" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Grades(Grade, GradeName, GradeGroup, GradeStepAmount, GradeNameCons, GradeFromDate, GradeToDate, GradeOrder, GradeCons) VALUES (@Grade, @GradeName, @GradeGroup, @GradeStepAmount, @GradeNameCons, @GradeFromDate, @GradeToDate, @GradeOrder, @GradeCons)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE Grades SET Grade = @GradeNValue, GradeName = @GradeNameNValue, GradeGroup = @GradeGroupNValue, GradeStepAmount = @GradeStepAmountNValue, GradeOrder = @GradeOrderNValue, GradeCons = @GradeConsNValue, GradeNameCons = @GradeNameConsNValue, GradeFromDate = @GradeFromDateNValue, GradeToDate = @GradeToDateNValue FROM Grades INNER JOIN GradeGroups ON Grades.GradeGroup = GradeGroups.GradeGroup WHERE (Grades.Grade = @Grade) AND (Grades.GradeName = @GradeName) AND (Grades.GradeGroup = @GradeGroup) AND (Grades.GradeStepAmount = @GradeStepAmount) AND (Grades.GradeOrder = @GradOrder) AND (Grades.GradeCons = @GraderCons) AND (Grades.GradeNameCons = @GradeNameCons) AND (Grades.GradeFromDate = @GradeFromDate) AND (Grades.GradeToDate = @GradeToDate)">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Grade" />
            </DeleteParameters>
             <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Grade" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="double" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Grade" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeName" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeGroup" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeStepAmount" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeNameCons" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeFromDate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeToDate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeOrder" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeCons" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeNameNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeGroupNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeStepAmountNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeOrderNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeConsNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeNameConsNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeFromDateNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeToDateNValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Grade" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeName" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeGroup" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeStepAmount" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradOrder" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GraderCons" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeNameCons" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeFromDate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="GradeToDate" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I did the select parameter but it didn't work still.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT Grades.Grade, Grades.GradeName, GradeGroups.GradeGroupName, Grades.GradeStepAmount, Grades.GradeOrder, Grades.GradeCons, Grades.GradeNameCons, Grades.GradeFromDate, Grades.GradeToDate FROM Grades LEFT OUTER JOIN GradeGroups ON GradeGroups.GradeGroup = Grades.GradeGroup where Grades.Grade = @Code"
```